# How to plot points on hexbin graph in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have one hexbin graphm but how to add some other points(such as two points (x1,y1)) into this graph ???

Thanks

```
x=log(PR)
y=log(CR)

xmin = x.min()
xmax = x.max()
ymin = y.min()
ymax = y.max()

x1=log(np.array([10,20]))
y1=log(np.array([10,20]))
plt.hexbin(x1, y1, bins='log',color='red')
plt.hexbin(x, y, bins='log', cmap=plt.cm.gist_ncar)
plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
plt.title("With a log color scale")
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label('log10(N)')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, depending on what you want to plot. Some examples:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import numpy as np

x=np.random.random(1000)
y=np.random.random(1000)

pl.figure()
pl.hexbin(x, y, gridsize=5, cmap=pl.cm.PuBu_r)
pl.scatter(0.2, 0.2, s=400)
pl.text(0.5, 0.5, 'a simple text')
pl.text(0.6, 0.6, 'an aligned text', va='center', ha='center')
pl.annotate("an annotation for that scatter point", (0.2, 0.2), (0.3, 0.3),\
    arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05))
```

[image]